# Invalid argument in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple template:

```
<div ng-view class="reveal-animation" >
<br/>
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p class="panel-title" data-i18n-attr="{title: 'common.needScriptTag'}"><strong data-i18n="common.componentJavascript">Component Javascript</strong> <em>({{ckpage.url}})</em></p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ckpage.components">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label ng-model="value.name" data-i18n-attr="{title: 'common.needScriptTag'}">{{value.name}} ({{value.vpath}})</label>
                            <!-- It is disabled for editing if the component is not editable -->
                            <textarea ng-disabled="!value.editable" class="form-control full-width input-sm" ng-model="value.dcrJavascript" id="key" rows="10" data-i18n-attr="{title: 'common.needScriptTag'}">{{value.dcrJavascript}}</textarea>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the ng-repeat is run I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid argument.
   at Anonymous function (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:70:389)
   at Anonymous function (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:95:497)
   at Anonymous function (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:128:379)
   at r.prototype.$digest (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:131:147)
   at r.prototype.$apply (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:76)
   at g (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:87:442)
   at T (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:92:50)
   at w.onload (http://7.28.108.148/iw-cc/seed/libs/angular-1.4.8/angular.min.js:93:78)
```

If I remove `ng-disabled="!value.editable"` and `ng-model="value.dcrJavascript"` from the `textarea` element the errors go away. `value.dcrJavascript` exists because `{{value.dcrJavascript}}` provides the correct value in the web page and debugging shows me that `value.editable` also exists.

The full page still works despite the errors, but I don't like having errors showing up that I can't explain because they could come back to bite me later.

Searching around I can't seem to find someone that has had this error.

Comment: what kind of object do you have in `ckpage.components`?

Comment: Why do you have `{{value.dcrJavascript}}` in your `textarea`.  The inner text should be handled by `ng-model`.  Try removing that and see if that works. I doubt this has anything to do with your repeater.

Comment: @andrepaulo It just contains a bunch of string values and one boolean.

Comment: @jusopi Ok. I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @jusopi Removing that solved the problem. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks @markbernard, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't the repeater.  The inner text of the `<textarea/>` should be handled by `ng-model`. Remove the inner `{{value. dcrJavascript}}`.  So instead of:

```
<textarea ng-disabled="!value.editable" 
          class="form-control full-width input-sm" 
          ng-model="value.dcrJavascript" 
          id="key" rows="10" 
          data-i18n-attr="{title: 'common.needScriptTag'}">

          {{value.dcrJavascript}}
</textarea>
```

Do this:

```
<textarea ng-disabled="!value.editable" 
          class="form-control full-width input-sm" 
          ng-model="value.dcrJavascript" 
          id="key" rows="10" 
          data-i18n-attr="{title: 'common.needScriptTag'}">
</textarea>
```

Comment: This is inherited code so I am learning angular as I go. I have similar errors in other templates and this has helped me solve those ones as well. Thanks again.